# Metrics score like precision, recall, accuracy, f1_measure in SKlearn python library coming same i.e constant

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In this project i am classifying sign language using different classifiers given below like knn,svm,naive bayes etc and also measuring their score using f1 measure, accuracy, precision and recall using sklearn library but they are all coming same i.e. for individual method f1_measure=accuracy=precision=recall.
PLease help.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB as nb
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as knn
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression as lr
import numpy as np
import sklearn.metrics as sm

train = pd.read_csv("train60.csv")
print(train.head())
y = np.array(train.pop('label'))
x = np.array(train)/255.
print("here1")
#train = dataset.iloc[:,1:].values
test = pd.read_csv("train40.csv")
label_test=np.array(test.pop('label'))
x_ = np.array(test)/255.
print("here2")

def calc_accuracy(method,label_test,pred):
    print("accuracy score for ",method,sm.accuracy_score(label_test,pred))
    print("precision_score for ",method,sm.precision_score(label_test,pred,average='micro'))
    print("f1 score for ",method,sm.f1_score(label_test,pred,average='micro'))
    print("recall score for ",method,sm.recall_score(label_test,pred,average='micro'))


def run_svm():
    clf=svm.SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo')
    print("svm started")
    clf.fit(x,y)
    #print clf.n_layers_
    pred=clf.predict(x_)
    #print(pred)
    np.savetxt('submission_svm.csv', np.c_[range(1,len(test)+1),pred], delimiter=',', header = 'ImageId,Label', comments = '', fmt='%d')
    calc_accuracy("SVM",label_test,pred)

def run_lr():
    clf = lr()
    print("lr started")
    clf.fit(x,y)
    #print clf.n_layers_
    pred=clf.predict(x_)
    #print(pred)
    np.savetxt('submission_lr.csv', np.c_[range(1,len(test)+1),pred], delimiter=',', header = 'ImageId,Label', comments = '', fmt='%d')
    calc_accuracy("Logistic regression",label_test,pred)


def run_nb():
    clf = nb()
    print("nb started")
    clf.fit(x,y)
    #print(clf.classes_)
    #print clf.n_layers_
    pred=clf.predict(x_)
    #print(pred)
    np.savetxt('submission_nb.csv', np.c_[range(1,len(test)+1),pred], delimiter=',', header = 'ImageId,Label', comments = '', fmt='%d')
    calc_accuracy("Naive Bayes",label_test,pred)


def run_knn():
    clf=knn(n_neighbors=3)
    print("knn started")
    clf.fit(x,y)
    #print(clf.classes_)
    #print clf.n_layers_
    pred=clf.predict(x_)
    #print(pred)
    np.savetxt('submission_knn.csv', np.c_[range(1,len(test)+1),pred], delimiter=',', header = 'ImageId,Label', comments = '', fmt='%d')
    calc_accuracy("K nearest neighbours",label_test,pred)

run_svm()
run_knn()
run_nb()
run_lr()
```

my output in shell is as follow:

```
svm started
accuracy score for  SVM 0.596358118361
precision_score for  SVM 0.596358118361
f1 score for  SVM 0.596358118361
recall score for  SVM 0.596358118361
knn started
accuracy score for  K nearest neighbours 0.656550328781
precision_score for  K nearest neighbours 0.656550328781
f1 score for  K nearest neighbours 0.656550328781
recall score for  K nearest neighbours 0.656550328781
nb started
accuracy score for  Naive Bayes 0.360647445625
precision_score for  Naive Bayes 0.360647445625
f1 score for  Naive Bayes 0.360647445625
recall score for  Naive Bayes 0.360647445625
lr started
accuracy score for  Logistic regression 0.601922104198
precision_score for  Logistic regression 0.601922104198
f1 score for  Logistic regression 0.601922104198
recall score for  Logistic regression 0.601922104198
```

also the first column in test and train is of label for 1977 & 2995 images respectively of sign language and each row is having label of the image followed by 9126 pixels of the single image.

```
>>> y
array([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 23, 23, 23], dtype=int64)
>>> len(y)
2995
>>> x
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       ..., 
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> len(x)
2995
>>> test.head()
   pixel0  pixel1  pixel2  pixel3  pixel4  pixel5  pixel6  pixel7  pixel8  \
0     255     255     255     255     255     255     255     255     255   
1     255     255     255     255     255     255     255     255     255   
2     255     255     255     255     255     255     255     255     255   
3     255     255     255     255     255     255     255     255     255   
4     255     255     255     255     255     255     255     255     255   

   pixel9    ...      pixel9206  pixel9207  pixel9208  pixel9209  pixel9210  \
0     255    ...            255        255        255        255        255   
1     255    ...            255        255        255        255        255   
2     255    ...            255        255        255        255        255   
3     255    ...            255        255        255        255        255   
4     255    ...            255        255        255        255        255   

   pixel9211  pixel9212  pixel9213  pixel9214  pixel9215  
0        255        255        255        255        255  
1        255        255        255        255        255  
2        255        255        255        255        255  
3        255        255        255        255        255  
4        255        255        255        255        255  

[5 rows x 9216 columns]
```

Comment: not sure but pop in train.pop('label') remove one element,you might be testing and training to one instance

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan That's exactly what's happening.

Comment: you should do something x=train["column1",column2","column3"],y=train["label"]

Comment: checked the length of y it's 2995 so not one instance.

Comment: did you check after pop? and you should check on y,because you train remain the same

Comment: it's actually popping out a whole column of 2995 lables

Comment: can you add a print of x,y? and also for test?

Comment: added the x, y print and test.head() because its large

Comment: the first column in test and train is of label for 1977 & 2995 images respectively of sign language and each row is having label of the image followed by 9126 pixels of the single image. @Eliethesaiyan